# sending emails to user with id extracted from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, csv

I have code which import CSV data in mysql with php, import is working fine but i need additional function which will send email to user by searching user_id from csv. I had converted csv to array $csv_array,

```
user_id     order    part

1           test     phone
1           another  pad
2           all      tab
```

Now, code will search user and get user_email from user database and then send email to user.

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {

                $this->load->library('email');
                $this->load->library('parser');

                $email = $this->admin_model->getEmailNotification();

                $user = $this->model->getUserShipment($row['user_id']);

                if(count($user) == 1)
                {
                    $data = array(  
                        'user_firstname' => $user->user_firstname,
                        'user_lastname' => $user->user_lastname,
                        'user_email' => $user->user_email,
                        );

                    $subject = 'Your Order has been shipped';
                    $message = $this->parser->parse('templates/update', $data, TRUE);

                    $config['protocol'] = $email->email_protocol;
                    $config['smtp_host'] = $email->email_host;
                    $config['smtp_user'] = $email->email_address;
                    $config['smtp_pass'] = $email->email_password;
                    $config['smtp_port'] = $email->email_port;
                    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

                    $this->email->initialize($config);

                    $this->email->from($email->email_address);
                    $this->email->to($user->user_email);  
                    $this->email->subject($subject);
                    $this->email->message($message);        

                    $this->email->send();
                }


            }
```

Now with this i have two problems,

1. This will send email for each row, but i want to send only 1 email with two orders, example, in above table, user_id 1 will get only 1 email with order and part information,
2. Also, how will i create array to pass in template for user_id-1 -> order and parts to put in table inside template?

Thanks,

Comment: Regarding your fist problem, how do you include your "order" and "part" data? Does it currently send out 2 emails with 2 orders or 2 emails with one single order?

Comment: @Silencio, Yes, currently i have not added as part of $data, but if i add 'order' => $row['order], then it will send 2 email with single single information

Comment: how do you want to include your order- and part-data? It woud be helpful if you coud add an example of your desired data-array.

Comment: @Silencio, it will be simple MD array like array( array('order' =>'test', 'part' => 'phone'), array('order' =>'another', 'part' => 'pad'))

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. It will only send an email when it detects a new user_id.

I extracted your email sending process into a function so I can call it after finishing reading the csv (otherwise the last user_id will get no email).

The array i created $orderandparts is formatted how you wanted it you just need to put it to use inside the function.

Code:

```
function sendmail($user_id,$orderandparts)
{
$this->load->library('email');
$this->load->library('parser');

$email = $this->admin_model->getEmailNotification();

$user = $this->model->getUserShipment($user_id);

if(count($user) == 1)
{
    $data = array(  
        'user_firstname' => $user->user_firstname,
        'user_lastname' => $user->user_lastname,
        'user_email' => $user->user_email,
        );

    $subject = 'Your Order has been shipped';
    $message = $this->parser->parse('templates/update', $data, TRUE);

    $config['protocol'] = $email->email_protocol;
    $config['smtp_host'] = $email->email_host;
    $config['smtp_user'] = $email->email_address;
    $config['smtp_pass'] = $email->email_password;
    $config['smtp_port'] = $email->email_port;
    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from($email->email_address);
    $this->email->to($user->user_email);  
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);        

    $this->email->send();
}
}
$user_id ="";
$orders = array();
$parts = array();
$orderandparts = array();
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
            if($user_id == "")
                $user_id = $row["user_id"];

            if($user_id == $row["user_id"])
            {
                array_push($orders,$row["orders"]);
                array_push($parts,$row["parts"]);
            }
            else//Sends mail if all user data has been finished (new user_id detected)
            {
            for($i;$i<count($orders);$i++)
            {
                $orderandparts[$i]["order"] = $orders[$i];
                $orderandparts[$i]["part"] = $orders[$i];
            }
            sendmail($user_id,$orderandparts);
            $user_id = $row["user_id"];
            unset($orders);
            unset($parts);
            unset($orderandparts);
            $orders = array();
            $parts = array();
            $orderandparts = array();
            array_push($orders,$row["orders"]);
            array_push($parts,$row["parts"]);
            for($i;$i<count($orders);$i++)
            {
                $orderandparts[$i]["order"] = $orders[$i];
                $orderandparts[$i]["part"] = $orders[$i];
            }
            }
}
sendmail($user_id,$orderandparts);
```